# Infragistics Grid Header Alignment Issue in all browsers except I.E

Tags: c#

I am using Infragistics version 7.1 (NetAdvantage 2008 vol 3 ) . I have a problem with UltraWebGrid headers alignment. when the grid is shown the headers of columns lose their alignment in all browsers except IE from content and footers I have already searched a lot for solution. Some solutions i tried are as follows:

```
1) Setting UseFixedHeaders to False.
2) Adding HtmlTextWriter in Render Event.
3) Setting Percentages for width rather than pixels.
4) Setting percentages for headers along with columns.
5) Adding Scrollbar button to Header along with other contents.
```

I cannot remove/ replace infragistics grid with some other sorcery. Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Aspx File:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.ExcelExport.v7.1,     Version=7.1.20071.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.ExcelExport" TagPrefix="igtblexp" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.Misc.v7.1, Version=7.1.20071.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.WebUI.Misc" TagPrefix="igmisc" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v7.1, Version=7.1.20071.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid" TagPrefix="igtbl" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="Server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function SetVerticalScrollBar() {
        var div   =  document.getElementById('ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_div'); 
        var hasVerticalScrollbar = div.scrollHeight > div.clientHeight;
        var div1 =   document.getElementById('ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_hdiv');
        //   alert(hasVerticalScrollbar);
        if (hasVerticalScrollbar) {

            div1.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
        } else {
            div1.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
        }
    }
</script>

<igmisc:WebAsyncRefreshPanel ID="WebAsyncRefreshPanel1" runat="server" Height="100%"
                InitializePanel="WebAsyncRefreshPanel1_InitializePanel"     RefreshComplete="WebAsyncRefreshPanel1_RefreshComplete" Width="100%" 
                ToolTip="Filter Records" RefreshTargetIDs="lblTest">


<igtbl:UltraWebGrid ID="gridReportMain" runat="server" OnInitializeLayout="gridReportMain_InitializeLayout"
                    OnInitializeRow="gridReportMain_InitializeRow" OnPageIndexChanged="gridReportMain_PageIndexChanged"
                    OnSortColumn="gridReportMain_SortColumn" Style="left: 0px; top: 0px" OnItemCommand="gridReportMain_ItemCommand"
                    Height="380px" Width="1000px">


</igtbl:UltraWebGrid>

            </igmisc:WebAsyncRefreshPanel>



Aspx.cs File


 protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(sb));
        //Render the page to the new HtmlTextWriter which actually writes to the stringbuilder 
        base.Render(tw);

        //Get the rendered content 
        string sContent = sb.ToString();
        // sContent=Util.SetCaptionWidth(sContent, gridReportMain);
        sContent = Util.HandleColGroup(sContent, null);

        //Now output it to the page, if you want 
        writer.Write(sContent);

        // .... render using the provided writUtier 
    }


 public void BindGrid()
 {
    gridReportMain.Columns.FromKey("col1").Width = Unit.Percentage(8);
    gridReportMain.Columns.FromKey("col1").CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    gridReportMain.Columns.FromKey("col2").Width = Unit.Percentage(17);
    gridReportMain.Columns.FromKey("col2").CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    gridReportMain.Columns.FromKey("col3").Width = Unit.Percentage(35);
    gridReportMain.Columns.FromKey("col3").CellStyle.Wrap = true;
    gridReportMain.Columns.FromKey("col3").CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
    gridReportMain.Columns.FromKey("col4").Width = Unit.Percentage(20);
    gridReportMain.Columns.FromKey("col4").CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    gridReportMain.Columns.FromKey("col5").CellStyle.Width = Unit.Percentage(20);
    gridReportMain.Columns.FromKey("col5").CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
}
```

---

//Rendered HTML of code by chrome browser is as follows

```
    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebAsyncRefreshPanel1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

        <input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridReportMain" name="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain" value="">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_main" style="overflow: hidden; table-layout: fixed; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 420px;" class="ig_a92c6fb9_0" onresize="igtbl_onResize('ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain');" onmousemove="igtbl_tableMouseMove(event,'ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain');" onmouseup="igtbl_tableMouseUp(event,'ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain');">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="">
                    <td align="left" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%;">
                        <div id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_hdiv" onscroll="igtbl_onStationaryMarginScroll(event, 'ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain', 'ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_hdiv')" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; position: relative;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="position: relative; table-layout: fixed; height: 100%; left: 0px;" bandno="0" width="100%">
                                <colgroup>
                                    <col width="3%">
                                    <col width="8%">
                                    <col width="17%">
                                    <col width="35%">
                                    <col width="20%">
                                    <col width="">
                                </colgroup>
                                <thead class="ig_a92c6fb9_2 ig_a92c6fb9_4" onmousedown="igtbl_headerClickDown(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmouseup="igtbl_headerClickUp(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmouseout="igtbl_headerMouseOut(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmousemove="igtbl_headerMouseMove(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmouseover="igtbl_headerMouseOver(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" oncontextmenu="igtbl_headerContextMenu(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" ondblclick="igtbl_cellDblClick(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th width="22px" height="21px">
                                            <img src="/WebResource.axd?d=7pWSBIm8MJIGEb1Wa5NJl8vAQvyUcqnpFOduPjzVgdJugewSUhKHTQd6piYU4mvepwpZ0y9a-4ZQxtK6QCPcx7x1pdSR9sId6hyI6JggZaIW2Azd88swUnViW5RwSJFzBhHQxK_x-HAm2_7aBziVikxEEMyVFLgBQCk5MN44TpZWHnFoRlSrLaRv4OPBV-S3SAn5Jw2&amp;t=634992170622404219" border="0" imgtype="blank" style="visibility: hidden;"></th>
                                        <th id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_c_0_0" columnno="0" height="21px">
                                            <nobr>col1</nobr>
                                        </th>
                                        <th id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_c_0_1" columnno="1" height="21px">
                                            <nobr>Col2</nobr>
                                        </th>
                                        <th id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_c_0_2" columnno="2" height="21px">
                                            <nobr>col3</nobr>
                                        </th>
                                        <th id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_c_0_3" columnno="3" height="21px">
                                            <nobr>Col4</nobr>
                                        </th>
                                        <th id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_c_0_4" columnno="4" height="21px">
                                            <nobr>col5</nobr>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_mr" style="height: 100%;">
                    <td id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_mc" align="left" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; vertical-align: top;">
                        <div id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_div" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-y: auto; width: 100%; height: 100%;" onscroll="igtbl_onScroll(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" tabindexpage="0" hidefocus="true">
                            <table id="G_ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain" bandno="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; position: relative;" onselectstart="igtbl_selectStart(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmousedown="igtbl_cellClickDown(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmouseup="igtbl_cellClickUp(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" oncontextmenu="igtbl_cellContextMenu(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmousemove="igtbl_cellMouseMove(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmouseover="igtbl_cellMouseOver(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmouseout="igtbl_cellMouseOut(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" ondblclick="igtbl_cellDblClick(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);">
                                <colgroup>
                                    <col width="3%">
                                    <col width="8%">
                                    <col width="17%">
                                    <col width="35%">
                                    <col width="20%">
                                    <col width="">
                                </colgroup>
                                <thead class="ig_a92c6fb9_2 ig_a92c6fb9_4" style="height: 21px; display: none;" onmousedown="igtbl_headerClickDown(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmouseup="igtbl_headerClickUp(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmouseout="igtbl_headerMouseOut(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmousemove="igtbl_headerMouseMove(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmouseover="igtbl_headerMouseOver(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" oncontextmenu="igtbl_headerContextMenu(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th height="21px">
                                            <img src="/WebResource.axd?d=7pWSBIm8MJIGEb1Wa5NJl8vAQvyUcqnpFOduPjzVgdJugewSUhKHTQd6piYU4mvepwpZ0y9a-4ZQxtK6QCPcx7x1pdSR9sId6hyI6JggZaIW2Azd88swUnViW5RwSJFzBhHQxK_x-HAm2_7aBziVikxEEMyVFLgBQCk5MN44TpZWHnFoRlSrLaRv4OPBV-S3SAn5Jw2&amp;t=634992170622404219" border="0" imgtype="blank" style="visibility: hidden;"></th>
                                        <th id="Th1" columnno="0" height="21px">&nbsp;</th>
                                        <th id="Th2" columnno="1" height="21px">&nbsp;</th>
                                        <th id="Th3" columnno="2" height="21px">&nbsp;</th>
                                        <th id="Th4" columnno="3" height="21px">&nbsp;</th>
                                        <th id="Th5" columnno="4" height="21px">&nbsp;</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody style="height: 100%" class="ig_a92c6fb9_2 ig_a92c6fb9_4">
                                    <tr id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_r_0" style="height: 21px;" level="0">
                                        <th id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_l_0" style="width: 22px; height: 21px;">
                                            <img src="/WebResource.axd?d=7pWSBIm8MJIGEb1Wa5NJl8vAQvyUcqnpFOduPjzVgdJugewSUhKHTQd6piYU4mvepwpZ0y9a-4ZQxtK6QCPcx7x1pdSR9sId6hyI6JggZaIW2Azd88swUnViW5RwSJFzBhHQxK_x-HAm2_7aBziVikxEEMyVFLgBQCk5MN44TpZWHnFoRlSrLaRv4OPBV-S3SAn5Jw2&amp;t=634992170622404219" border="0" imgtype="blank" style="visibility: hidden;"></th>
                                        <td class="ig_a92c6fb9_15" level="0_0" id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_rc_0_0">
                                            <nobr>1</nobr>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="ig_a92c6fb9_16" level="0_1" id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_rc_0_1">
                                            <nobr><div style="text-align:center">row1col2</div></nobr>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="ig_a92c6fb9_17" level="0_2" id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_rc_0_2">
                                            <div style="text-align: left">Row1Col3</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="ig_a92c6fb9_18" level="0_3" id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_rc_0_3">
                                            <nobr><div style="text-align:center">row1col4</div></nobr>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="ig_a92c6fb9_19" level="0_4" id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_rc_0_4">
                                            <nobr><div style="text-align:right">row1col5</div></nobr>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot class="ig_a92c6fb9_2 ig_a92c6fb9_4 ig_a92c6fb9_5" style="height: 21px;" onmousedown="igtbl_headerClickDown(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmouseup="igtbl_headerClickUp(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmouseout="igtbl_headerMouseOut(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmousemove="igtbl_headerMouseMove(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" onmouseover="igtbl_headerMouseOver(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);" oncontextmenu="igtbl_headerContextMenu(event,&quot;ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain&quot;);">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th height="21px">
                                            <img src="/WebResource.axd?d=7pWSBIm8MJIGEb1Wa5NJl8vAQvyUcqnpFOduPjzVgdJugewSUhKHTQd6piYU4mvepwpZ0y9a-4ZQxtK6QCPcx7x1pdSR9sId6hyI6JggZaIW2Azd88swUnViW5RwSJFzBhHQxK_x-HAm2_7aBziVikxEEMyVFLgBQCk5MN44TpZWHnFoRlSrLaRv4OPBV-S3SAn5Jw2&amp;t=634992170622404219" border="0" imgtype="blank" style="visibility: hidden;"></th>
                                        <th id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_f_0_0" height="21px" key="col1">&nbsp;</th>
                                        <th id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_f_0_1" height="21px" key="col2">
                                            <nobr>Total</nobr>
                                        </th>
                                        <th id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_f_0_2" height="21px" key="col3">&nbsp;</th>
                                        <th id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_f_0_3" height="21px" key="SubmissionDate">&nbsp;</th>
                                        <th id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain_f_0_4" height="21px" key="TotalValueOfServices">
                                            <nobr>10,302</nobr>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 1%">
                    <td id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridReportMain_pager" align="Right" class="ig_a92c6fb9_0 ig_a92c6fb9_1" style="border-top-width: 0px; height: 100%;" onclick="igtbl_onPagerClick('ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xgridReportMain',event)">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you able to post a small sample of the rendered HTML? I have a suspicion that a control that old is using deprecated attributes.

Comment: Rendered html of the control has been added to the post.